# Logback Configuration file

Tags: slf4j, logback

I am brand new to logback, and have a general question. I will be developing in Eclipse and was wondering where do I place my configuration files. For example my class Test.java is located in ProjectName/src/default package/Test.java

Where do I put the configuration file? Do I need to create a new folder or place it in the same place?

Answer (score 5):

The configuration files need to be on the classpath, at the root. I would suggest you create a directory for classpath resources, and put it in there - we usually have a directory called 'resource' right next to the 'src' directory. Then add that to the classpath - in the Build Path dialog box, add it as a 'class folder' (not as a source folder!).

You can just put logback.xml straight in that directory.

Answer (score -3):

Configuration files usually go in the ProjectName/bin folder

Comment: No way! `bin` is for _binary_ files, usually compiled `.class` files

Comment: @Daniel: Where i come from, bin is for executable files, which, perversely, are usually textual shell scripts. But definitely not configuration files.